# Error getting messages content-type using Javamail in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, content-type, pop3

I am trying to read an email message using `Javamail` in `Java` (using `POP3 protocol`).

When I do it, it read the message as a `multipart/mixed` with `text/plain`. The headers are:

```
Content-type: multipart/mixed; 
    Boundary="0__=4EBB09EBDFBA95FA8f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB09EBDFBA95FA"
Content-type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

But it is not right, because when I save the message using Lotus Notes, the real headers are:

```
Content-type: multipart/mixed; 
    Boundary="0__=4EBB09EBDFBCF4F08f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB09EBDFBCF4F0"
--0__=4EBB09EBDFBCF4F08f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB09EBDFBCF4F0
Content-type: multipart/related; 
    Boundary="1__=4EBB09EBDFBCF4F08f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB09EBDFBCF4F0"
--1__=4EBB09EBDFBCF4F08f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB09EBDFBCF4F0
Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

This difference causes I get the body text in an incorrect format, getting a lot of tabulations and end-of-lines that I should not get.

I would like to know why this is happening and how it can be solved.

Comment: Are you reading the message from a Lotus Notes server?  Lotus Notes may be converting the format of the message before returning it via POP3, to support older email clients that don't understand multipart/related.

Comment: Yes, it is my case. Does this trouble have any solution?

Comment: I don't know.  You probably need to talk to your Lotus Notes administrator.